# How to number split output files using %02d from “01” in FFmpeg”

Tags: ffmpeg, numbering

Using latest FFmpeg on Windows 7 within an AutoHotkey routine

Is there a way to get FFmpeg to number the output files from `01`? This line of code works as expected except `%02d` returns the first file as `Output_00.mp3`

```
ffmpeg -i "%SelectedFile%" -c copy -map 0:0 -segment_time %Seg% -f segment -start_number 1 "%dir%\%name_no_ext%_`%02d.%ext%"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the segment muxer, the syntax is `-segment_start_number 1`